# Use MemoryStream and ZipArchive to return zip file to client in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

I am trying to return zip file from asp.net web api to client using The following Code:

```
private byte[] CreateZip(string data)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var ar = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var file = archive.CreateEntry("file.html");

            using (var entryStream = file.Open())
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
            {
                sw .Write(value);
            }
        }
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string data)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(CreateZip(data));
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip, application/octet-stream");
    return result;
}
```

When i run this code i get the following error:

> ExceptionMessage":"The format of value 'application/zip,
>   application/octet-stream' is invalid."

this is the JS code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
});
```

Any explanation why this is happen? I would really appriciate your help guys

Comment: Show your javascript code. And have you tried return ResponseMessage(result) instead?

Comment: @RicardoPontual see update. and no i  didnt use ResponseMessage(result)

Comment: @RicardoPontual should i use it instead of result.Content.Headers.ContentType??

Comment: Is your API code working properly? did you try for testing saving the file on the disk? I just want to make sure that the issue is on the JavaScript and not on the API.

Comment: i tried this from console application without memory stream actually and it was saving locally yeah..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$.ajax` handles text responses and will try to (utf-8) decode the content: your zip file isn't text, you will get a corrupted content. jQuery doesn't support binary content so you need to use [this](http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/) link and add an ajax transport on jQuery or use directly a XmlHttpRequest. With an xhr, you need to set `xhr.responseType = "blob"` and read from `xhr.response` the blob.

```
// with xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer"
var arraybuffer = xhr.response;
var blob = new Blob([arraybuffer], {type:"application/zip"});
saveAs(blob, "example.zip");

// with xhr.responseType = "blob"
var blob = xhr.response;
saveAs(blob, "example.zip");
Edit: examples:
```

with [jquery.binarytransport.js](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport)  (any library that let you download a Blob or an ArrayBuffer will do)

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "binary", // to use the binary transport
  // responseType:'blob', this is the default
  data: data,
  processData: false,
  success: function (blob) {
    // the result is a blob, we can trigger the download directly
    saveAs(blob, "example.zip");
  }
  // [...]
});
```

with a raw XMLHttpRequest, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest) question, you just need to add a `xhr.responseType = "blob"` to get a blob.

I personally recommended you to use an ajax transport on jQuery, that's very easy, you have to download a library, include it in the project and write: `dataType: "binary".`

This is the API code, using DotNetZip (`Ionic.Zip`):

```
   [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage ZipDocs([FromBody] string[] docs)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            //this code takes an array of documents' paths and Zip them
            zip.AddFiles(docs, false, "");
            return ZipContentResult(zip);
        }
    }

    protected HttpResponseMessage ZipContentResult(ZipFile zipFile)
    {
        var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
        {
          zipFile.Save(stream);
            stream.Close(); 
        }, "application/zip");

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = pushStreamContent };
    }
```

Comment: i tried both but are not working for me :/ i dont get the error anymore but the file is not downloaded'

Comment: i dont see any problem on my backend part do u ??http://postimg.org/image/3m861h77f/

Comment: Did you check the Consol on the Developers Tool (F12)? Are there any error? I personaly did it using DotNetZip library and not using ZipArchive.

Answer (score 10):

Here is my solution that worked for me

**C# side**

```
public IActionResult GetZip([FromBody] List<DocumentAndSourceDto> documents)
{
    List<Document> listOfDocuments = new List<Document>();

    foreach (DocumentAndSourceDto doc in documents)
        listOfDocuments.Add(_documentService.GetDocumentWithServerPath(doc.Id));

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (var attachment in listOfDocuments)
            {
                var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(attachment.FileName);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(attachment.FilePath, FileMode.Open))
                using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                {
                    fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                }
            }

        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip");
    }

    throw new ErrorException("Can't zip files");
}
```

don't miss the `ms.Position = 0;` here

**Front side** (Angular 4) :

```
downloadZip(datas: any) {
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/zip'
    });

    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true, responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer });
    const body = JSON.stringify(datas);
    return this.authHttp.post(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}api/documents/zip`, body, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const blob = new Blob([response.blob()], { type: 'application/zip' });
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'logs.zip');
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Now I'm able to download multiple files to zip.

Comment: ` ms.Position = 0` does not need to be called. [ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) writes the stream to a byte array regardless of position.

Comment: @ScottClark without I couldn't get my code work as expected :/

Comment: @Fitch Does the download starts immediately? Or we have to wait till all files are zipped and then download starts?

Comment: @ShyamalParikh It does wait that all files are zipped then download starts

Comment: C# part finished my eternity suffering (that copying streams part). Thanks

Comment: I was setting stream into response content but was getting empty zip on client side finally adding "ms.Position = 0" solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

### **This is suitable for asp.net core version.**

```
    [HttpGet("api/DownloadZip")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
    {
        var path = "C:\\test.zip";
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }

        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
    }
```

### *Then use Web client call*

```
      class Program
    {

        static string url = "http://localhost:5000/api/DownloadZip";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = @"c:\temp1\test.zip";

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), p);                       

            Console.WriteLine("ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of the value you are passing into the constructor of the `MediaTypeHeaderValue` is invalid. You are also trying to add multiple content types to the header value.

Content type header takes a single type/subtype, followed by optional parameters separated with semi-colons `;`

eg:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4
```

For your result you need to decide on which one you want to use.  `application/zip` or `application/octet-stream`

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
```

Also, to avoid exception you can use the `MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse` method

```
var contentTypeString = "application/zip";
MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType = null;
if(MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(contentTypeString, out contentType)) {
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = contentType;
}
```

Comment: U cannot assign null to implicity type variable var contentType = null, this is wrong

Comment: @Kob_24 that was a typo on my part. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return it as a downloadable file. Try this. Return type can be IActionResult

```
 var theJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
            using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
                {
                    var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("data.json");
                    using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                    using (var jsonStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
                    {
                        jsonStreamWriter.Write(theJson);
                    }
                }
                // Reset zip stream to point at the beginning of data
                zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                // Set the response headers
                //Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=compressed_response.zip");
                // Return zip file containing JSON data as response
                return File(zipStream.ToArray(), "application/zip");
            }
```