# Convert HttpResponseBase to IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

How to implement the following function in IHttpActionResult action, Web API controller?

Do I need to modify the `HttpResponseBase` to something else?

```
public void ZipFilesToResponse(HttpResponseBase response, IEnumerable<Asset> files, string zipFileName)
{
    using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.OutputStream))
    {
        zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression
        response.BufferOutput = false;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);
        response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var entry = new ZipEntry(file.FilenameSlug())
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                Size = file.Filesize
            };
            zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
            storageService.ReadToStream(file, zipOutputStream);
            response.Flush();
            if (!response.IsClientConnected)
            {
               break;
            }
        }
        zipOutputStream.Finish();
        zipOutputStream.Close();
    }
    response.End();
}
```

To be utilized here:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("DownloadFiles/{company_id}")]
public IHttpActionResult DownloadFiles(Int64 company_id, TasksFilterModel searchModel)
{
     var files = .....;
     ZipFilesToResponse(_______,files,"download.zip");
     return ????
}
```

Comment: I don't have the full answer, but it may help to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397666/1220550

Answer (score 1):

Your current `ZipFilesToResponse` method is built more for regular MVC, not Web API. One option would be to simply move this action into an MVC controller instead of a Web API controller.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DownloadFiles/{company_id}")]
    public void DownloadFiles(Int64 company_id, TasksFilterModel searchModel)
    {
         var files = ...;
         ZipFilesToResponse(HttpContext.Response, files, "download.zip");
    }
}
```

You do not need to return anything since your `ZipFilesToResponse` method writes directly to the HttpContext.Response object.

Alternatively, if you want to stick with purely Web API, we can modify the `ZipFilesToResponse` method to create a `HttpResponseMessage`, and then return that from your action.

```
[Route("DownloadFiles")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFiles()
{
    var files = ...;
    return ZipContentResult(files, "download.zip");
}

protected HttpResponseMessage ZipContentResult(IEnumerable<Asset> files, string zipFileName)
{
    var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
    {
        using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(stream))
        {
            zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var entry = new ZipEntry(file.FilenameSlug())
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    Size = file.Filesize
                };
                zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                storageService.ReadToStream(file, zipOutputStream);
                stream.Flush();
             }
             zipOutputStream.Finish();
             zipOutputStream.Close();
        }
        stream.Close();
    }, "application/zip");

    pushStreamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = pushStreamContent };
}
```

Comment: Also, to return an IHttpActionResult in DownloadFiles with your code one can write `return ResponseMessage(ZipContentResult(files));`. Although it doesn't really gives any additional benefit.

Comment: On the frontend download doesn't begin automatically. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @ShyamalParikh What happens when you hit the endpoint (/DownloadFiles/...)? Any errors returned? I realized in my second example I used [HttpGet] instead of [HttpPost], make sure to change that to fit your requirements.

Comment: The client receives the file however download modal isn't trigger to save the file on client

Comment: Ok so the download is being triggered however, there's an error on opening the zip file